# Extracting Microsoft Office installer from Dell OEM CDs

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I have a Dell desktop computer that comes pre-installed with Windows 7 and Office 2010. The Office 2010 installation somehow got corrupted and I need to reinstall it.

Dell supplied me with 3 CD; Drivers and Documentations, Resource Media and Operating System. However, I can't seem to locate the Office 2010 installation files in any of these CDs.

I understand that these files can be downloaded from Microsoft's website as I have the product activation key card but my Internet speed is somewhat slow as I'm on 3G connectivity. Is there anyway I can extract the Microsoft Office 2010 installer from any of these CDs?

Comment: Open the Install.wim on the OS media with 7zip (http://7-zip.org/) and look for an Office folder in ProgramData

Comment: If you load the CDs doesn't a menu pop up asking you what you want to do?

Comment: No. The Operating System media, in fact, states that it is not for reinstallation of programs or drivers.

Comment: have you looked inside the install.wim?

Comment: ProgramData has 7 folders. I have checked on each one of them incl. Microsoft and there is no Office folder in it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Dell ships the Office media anymore (even when you order the media set).

From [here](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?docid=266613)

> Dell no longer ships hard media for Microsoft Office products with
>   computers. If it becomes necessary to restore your computer to its
>   original factory settings, you will need to download the Trial Version
>   of Microsoft Office 2010 and activate it using the MPI card
>   [as instructed below](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?docid=DSN_370455&isLegacy=true#Issue6).

So just download the corresponding trial-version and use your key with that.